# Parse Server Token Verification

Tags: parse-platform, token, parse-server

I'm trying to move an app from using Firebase as a backend to Parse Server.

My app uses an Azure .NET API. I use the FB token to ensure it is being called by a registered user. Currently with Firebase it gets the Firebase token using

`this.user.getIdTokenResult()`

This is sent to the Azure API in the header, which uses `FirebaseAuth VerifyIdTokenAsync` to verify.

Now using Parse I get the token client side using (.NET) `ParseSession.GetCurrentSessionAsync()`.

From my Azure API, is there a method/rest endpoint in Parse to call that is equivalent to the Firebase VerifyIdTokenAsync?

Comment: have you tried the [becomeAsync](https://docs.parseplatform.org/dotnet/guide/#setting-the-current-user) function?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo - That seems to be it!. Thanks

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Can you post it as a response so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: Glad to know it worked. I've just post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [becomeAsync](https://docs.parseplatform.org/dotnet/guide/#setting-the-current-user) function.